# Dockerfile ADD https://zzzz x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I have a Dockerfile and one of the actions is to add an xml file downloaded from a stash ( internal network) repository. We use self certs for our stash. I am getting this error "Centos docker x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" at the step when it tries to execute the ADD command (which results in a http GET)
Any solution to by pass?

Comment: There are several solutions.  There are already documents out there that describe how to update your CentOS host to recognize a new certificate authority.  You could also use something like `curl` or `wget` via a `RUN` command, rather than using `ADD`, and instruct your command line tool to ignore invalid certificates.

Comment: Still no clean solution to this problem without changing your dockerfile to use curl instead?